# Missing "Document Sets" in Site Collection features

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to configure Document libraries to use Document sets? 
(https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-manage-document-sets-c71d5796-d559-48de-b1b3-42383bdd13ea)
Document sets is missing in Site Collection features of Sharepoint Online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Document Sets feature has not been activated for your site collection, you will need to activate it before you can create or configure new Document Set content types. You must be a **Site Collection Administrator** to activate the Document Sets feature.

1. Go to the top-level site in the site collection for which you want
   to enable Document Sets.
2. On the Site Actions menu, click Site Settings.
3. Under Site Collection Administration, click Site collection
   features.
4. Find Document Sets in the list, and then click Activate.
   [image]

Comment: I am a site collection administrator
I go to the site settings -> site features menu: `/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx`
I do not see `Document Sets`. I only see https://pastebin.com/rMiQpmvA
what am I missing here?

Comment: ah i clicked wrong menu. correct menu is `/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site`

Answer (score 1):

That feature shows up in all of my sites, including a very recent tenant.

- are you a Site Collection Administrator?
- are you looking in Site Collection Features and not Manage Site Features?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I contact my Site Collection Administrator.